# Setting up a twitter button return [object Object] instead of the value

Tags: reactjs, object

I am a beginner in reactjs and was wondering why my twitter-tweet button doesn`t work as expected.

**Intended behaviour:** Clicking the button *should* copy the quote to the twitter mask

**Present behaviour:** Clicking the button yields `[object Object]--[object Object]`, which appears on twitter.

Can someone tell me a way to fix this issue? Here is my Code:

```
class Quotes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      quotes: [],
      rndNum: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500)
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillMount = () => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ quotes: data }));
  };
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ rndNum: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) });
  }

  render() {
    // now, the console.log below returns the random object,
    // but if I add a ".body",
    // it returns undefined. Why does it return undefined?

    console.log(this.state.quotes[this.state.rndNum]);

    const postAuthor = this.state.quotes.map(quote => (
      <div key={quote.id}>
        <h3>{quote.email}</h3>
      </div>
    ));

    const postQuote = this.state.quotes.map(quote => (
      <div key={quote.id}>
        <h3>{quote.body}</h3>
      </div>
    ));

    let randomQuote = postQuote[this.state.rndNum];

    let randomAuthor = postAuthor[this.state.rndNum];

    return (
      <div id="Wrapper" style={outerDiv}>
        <div id="text">
          <h2>{randomQuote}</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="author">
          <h4>{randomAuthor}</h4>
        </div>
        <button id="new-quote" onClick={this.handleClick} style={button}>
          New Quote
        </button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a
          className="twitter-share-button"
          id="tweet-quote"
          href={`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${randomQuote}--${randomAuthor}`}
        >
          Tweet this one!
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: You will soon learn that in the world of javascript that an `[Object object]` means that the parameter "EXPECTED" is a non-object type ie: string or int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the defined randomQuote & randomAuthor.

```
<a className="twitter-share-button" id="tweet-quote" href={`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${randomQuote}--${randomAuthor}`}>Tweet this one!</a>
```

Try to define the quote and author like that. In order to make sure that the desired state & object is already available, just bring in a little check before assigning the content to the constant.

```
const selectedQuote = this.state.quotes[this.state.rndNum];
const quote = selectedQuote && selectedQuote.body;
const author = selectedQuote && selectedQuote.email;
```

And use it in your return like:

```
<a className="twitter-share-button" id="tweet-quote" href={`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${quote}--${author}`}>Tweet this one!</a>
```

**Why do I need to check whether `this.state.quotes[this.state.rndNum]` is already available?**
Although you are triggering the data fetch in your componentWillMount(), it is not ensured that the state will be populated with the data once it renders the first time. That is why you need to check whether the data is actually available - otherwise you are trying to access something that is simply not there, what will result in the error you experienced.

Another hint: Please have a look into react component lifecycles:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html
`componentWillMount()` is deprecated and shouldn't be used from React 16 on.

Comment: thank you for this reply. Unfortunatly React answers with ```this.state.quotes[this.state.rndNum].body is undefined```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for this reply. Unfortunatly React answers with

```
this.state.quotes[this.state.rndNum].body is undefined
```

At the moment I can`t figure out why it is like it is.
Does the function to create the rndNum in the state can be the reason for this?
I will make up my mind regarding another solution :)

Best regards from Duisburg.

Comment: This will happen if your array does not contain an entry with index rndNum.
How does your this.state.quotes look like with a console.log?

Comment: its undefined because it does not accept the .body property, but I can`t figur out why a combination of .body and [rndNum] is not possible.

Comment: Can you do a console.log(this.state.quotes); in your render part and show what it looks like?

Comment: ```Object { postId: 20, id: 99, name: "laudantium delectus nam", email: "Hildegard.Aufderhar@howard.com", body: "aut quam consequatur sit et\nrepellat maiores laborum similique voluptatem necessitatibus nihil\net debitis nemo occaecati cupiditate\nmodi dolorum quia aut" }```

Comment: console.log(this.state.quotes[this.state.rndNum]); return the comment above, but if I extend this with a ```.body``` doesnt work.

Comment: You are welcome. I updated my answer with further explanations.